# Inexplicably unable to locate a specific element in an array

Tags: javascript, search

I'm trying to make a twitch bot where people can join 2 lists and interact with it in the context of what I'm making it for. Everything is getting tracked inside a csv file. I added a '!remove' command that takes in a mention for a person and tries to remove them from whichever line they are in. This command works for everyone, but for some reason, this is not working for one specific person and I cannot figure out why. Below is the code stub for that portion of the code, and below that is an output sent in twitch chat.

```
    if (!message.includes("@")) {
        client.say(channel, "Please include a mention for the user you want to remove, and only one at a time");
        return;
    }
    let person = message.slice(message.indexOf("@")).toLocaleLowerCase();
    for (let i = 0; i < arenaDetails.q1.length; i++) {
        if (person == arenaDetails.q1[i]){
            arenaDetails.q1.splice(i, 1);
            client.say(channel, person + " has been successfully removed!");
            updateCSV();
            return;
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arenaDetails.q2.length; i++) {
        if (person == arenaDetails.q2[i]){
            arenaDetails.q2.splice(i, 1);
            client.say(channel, person + " has been successfully removed!");
            updateCSV();
            return;
        }
    }
    //client.say(channel, "That person isn't in queue.");
    let text = "That person isn't in queue. Arena 1 has ";
    for (let perso of arenaDetails.q1) {
        text += '"' + perso + '",';
    }
    text += " and Arena 2 has ";
    for (let perso of arenaDetails.q2) {
        text += '"' + perso + '",';
    }
    text += " and you typed \"" + person + "\"";
    client.say(channel, text);
    return;
```

Inside the twitch chat, this is one of the outputs that the bot gave

```
User: !remove @Toronguito

bot: That person isn't in queue. Arena 1 has "@toronguito","@cornerglitchssbu","@yesitskiki","@treyarassb", and Arena 2 has "@shylahsky","@starlord357dx","@redsk02", and you typed "@toronguito"
```

I tried checking for an odd character by copying the name in queue and the name searched for and comparing them, but they returned that they were equal. This code worked for every other person inside the queue. There were other things that happened inexplicably with the code and this is one of them. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you copy and paste both of those chat messages as text instead of picture?

Comment: I have editted the post to remove the picture and replace it with a copy paste of the chat messages.

Comment: OK, I thought there might be something with the characters going on, but apparently they're exactly the same. I assume that `arenaDetails.q1` and `arenaDetails.q2` are just arrays of strings, right?

Comment: Correct. They are just arrays of strings

Comment: Then I don't know, sorry. My last idea would be to turn all the characters in those strings to code points and then log them and see if there's something going on there.